# How to get auto-generated ID of newly created document in a subcollection in Firestore Web V9? Javascript/React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

onClick I create a new document within a subcollection with a user's document.

Here's that function:

```
// Create a new checkout session in the subcollection inside this users document

const createCheckoutSession = async () => {
const collectionRef = collection(db, 'users', currentUser.uid, 'checkout_sessions');
const payload = {
  price: 'price_1JvjWLChfN4TVWbYw2LdDXZZ',
  success_url: window.location.origin,
  cancel_url: window.location.origin
};

await addDoc(collectionRef, payload);

// TODO – Get the newly created document's id. 

};
```

My goal is to get the newly created document's ID. To then get a field within that document to fire off a redirect to Stripe checkout.

In Firestore Web V8, I'm pretty certain I would use:

```
collectionRef.onSnapshot(async (snap) => {
  const { sessionId } = snap.data();
   if (sessionId) {
     // We have a session, let's redirect to Checkout
     // Init Stripe
     const stripe = await getStripe();
     stripe.redirectToCheckout({ sessionId });
   }
});
```

How can I get the newly created document's ID list as `// TODO` above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`addDoc` function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.md#adddoc) returns a `Promise<DocumentReference>` to the newly added document. So you cna get the ID with:

```
const docRef = await addDoc(collectionRef, payload);

console.log(docRef.id);
```

Comment: That worked. Thank you, Frank!